# How to load another html inside index.html on click Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a index.html file which was a button. I have a modal.html file which has a custom modal built. I want to `onclick` event render modal.html inside index.html and close it normally. Can anyone help me with the pure Javascript function?

index.html below example

```
<div id="modal-container">
// here I want to load content from modal.html
</div>
```

modal.html

```
<div>
//here is modal content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There used to be `frame` tags that allowed you to load other html pages from other addresses. but HTML5 does not support it i guess.

you can create elements and add attributes to create the modal you wish dynamically using js, then find the modal-container element and append it as a child. then add listeners or queries to open and close it.

or use modals provided by [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

or use check this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file) which is trying to import and use `.html` files inside another html file

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how to render a `.html` file into another.

### Using `iframe` tag

> An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current
> HTML document.

```html
<iframe src="modal.html"></iframe>
```

### Using jQuery

Specifically using jQuery's `.get()` method:

```js
$.get("modal.html", function(data) {
   $("#modal-container").html(data);
});
```

### Using PHP

```php
<?php include 'modal.html'?>
```

In your case, you could use the jQuery's `$.get()` method.